# Why do I get null characters at the end of my files when encoding and decoding?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, filereader

I'm making a web app that encodes an input file into a canvas element based on the char codes of each character in the input file.

For instance ABC, being `0x41`, `0x42` and `0x43` would make the color code `#414243`, and so on for the entire file.

A canvas element is then updated with the color codes to create a downloadable image.

To decode, there is a function that goes through each part of the uploaded image file, gets the color code and converts it back into characters based on the color values.

The issue is, I'm getting NUL characters at the end of the decoded file, and I'm at my wits end about how to handle these.

Here's the full JS code

```
function getFile (inp, encode=true){
  //no return
  let file = inp.files[0];
  let fr = new FileReader();

  if (encode){
    fr.readAsText(file);
    fr.onload = function(){
      let hexCodes = colorCode (fr.result, file['name']);
      let imgMain = document.getElementById ("main-canvas");
      imgMain.width = hexCodes.length;
      imgMain.height = 100;
      let ctx = imgMain.getContext("2d");
      for (let i=0;i<hexCodes.length;++i){
        ctx.fillStyle = hexCodes[i];
        ctx.fillRect (i,0,i+1,100);
      }
    };
  }else{
    fr.readAsDataURL(file);
    fr.onload = function(){
      var imgTmp = new Image();
      imgTmp.src = fr.result;
      imgTmp.onload = function(){
        let tmpDecode = colorDecode(imgTmp);
        let link = document.getElementById("download-link");
        link.download = tmpDecode[0];
        let tmpBlob = new Blob ([tmpDecode[1]],{type: 'text/plain'});
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(tmpBlob);
      }
    }
  }
  
  fr.onerror = function(){
    console.log (fr.error);
  };
}

function rbg(r,g,b){
  //returns an HTML color code
  let rR = "0"+r.toString(16);
  let rG = "0"+g.toString(16);
  let rB = "0"+b.toString(16);
  rR = rR.substr(rR.length - 2);
  rG = rG.substr(rG.length - 2);
  rB = rB.substr(rB.length - 2);
  return "#" + rR + rG + rB;
}

function colorCode(strInp, strName){
  //returns an array of color codes;
  let colors    = [[],[],[]];
  let colorsHex = [];
  while(strName.length<256)
    strName += String.fromCharCode (0);
  let wholeStr = strName + strInp;
  for(let i=0;i<wholeStr.length;++i){
    colors[i%3].push(wholeStr[i].charCodeAt(0));
  }
  if (colors[0].length>colors[1].length)
    colors[1].push(0);
  if (colors[1].length>colors[2].length)
    colors[2].push(0);
  for (let i=0;i<colors[0].length;++i){
    colorsHex.push(rbg(colors[0][i],colors[1][i],colors[2][i]));
  }
  return colorsHex;
}

function colorDecode(imgInp){
  //returns text value of file
  let imgMain = document.createElement ("canvas");
  let ctx = imgMain.getContext("2d");
  imgMain.width = imgInp.width;
  if (imgMain.width < 256)
    return "Image is not of correct length!";
  imgMain.height = imgInp.height;
  ctx.drawImage (imgInp, 0, 0);
  let retVal = "";
  let name = "";
  for (let i=0;i<86;++i){
    let p = ctx.getImageData(i,10,1,1).data;
    if (p[0] === 0)
      break;
    name += String.fromCharCode (p[0]);
    if (i!==86){
      if (p[1] === 0)
        break;
      name += String.fromCharCode (p[1]);
      if (p[2] === 0)
        break;
      name += String.fromCharCode (p[2]);
    }
  }
  name += String.fromCharCode(0); //ensures it's null terminated
  for (let i=85;i<imgMain.width;++i){
    let p = ctx.getImageData(i,10,1,1).data;
    if (i!==85)
      retVal += String.fromCharCode(p[0]);
    retVal += String.fromCharCode(p[1]);
    retVal += String.fromCharCode(p[2]);
  }
  while(retVal[-1]===String.fromCharCode(0) ||
        retVal[-1]===String.fromCharCode(32))
    retVal = retVal.substr(0,retVal.length-1);
  return [name.substring(0,name.length-1), retVal];
}
```

And here's the HTML just in case it's relevant

```
<doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Color Coder</title>
    <script src="colorCoder.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <label for="inp">Select a file to convert</label>
    <input type="file" id="inp" onchange="getFile(this)">
    <br>
    <canvas id="main-canvas" height=100></canvas>
    <br>
    <label for="inpDecode">Select an image to decode</label>
    <input type="file" id="inpDecode" onchange="getFile(this, false)">
    <br>
    <a id="download-link" download href="javascript:alert('Nothing to download!');">Download</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I know I'm adding char values 0 at the end of the strings, but shouldn't

```
while(retVal[-1]===String.fromCharCode(0) ||
        retVal[-1]===String.fromCharCode(32))
    retVal = retVal.substr(0,retVal.length-1);
```

take care of removing those NUL characters?

I've tried changing readAsText to readAsBinaryString, still get similar (the same?) issues.

I'm downloading the images as .PNG, and while I don't know, it doesn't look like it's losing resolution at any point.

## Edit for Clarity

The specific test case I'm using to get this behavior is using the colorCode.js (copied above in its entirety) as the source file to generate the PNG image and I'm getting NUL characters (ascii 0) along with space characters (ascii 32) appended to the end of the input.

Comment: What should happen if the file length isn't a multiple of 3 bytes?

Comment: @Barmar the conditionals at the end of `colorCode`, just before the for loop, adds char code 0 where those bytes should be. Then the while loop just before the return statement in `colorDecode` is supposed to delete those from the end of the return string.

Comment: But what if the file actually contains 0 bytes? How do you distinguish the ones that should be kept from those to remove?

Comment: @Barmar an empty file would encode with no problem but throw an error in the decode function because it would try to call `retVal.substr(0,-1)`, but that’s not what causes the behavior described in the post. Trying to get the car running before I spend any time designing seatbelts if that makes sense.

Comment: Not an empty file, a file with bytes whose values are 0. This is common in binary files.

Comment: @Barmar that's a good point. I've edited the question to clarify that I'm currently only using the colorCoder.js file as input to debug. The final character is a newline, but in debugging it shows up as a space or NUL. Of the 2, I suppose NUL makes more sense, but I feel like the while loop at the end of `colorDecode` should take off all the NUL characters.

Comment: FYI `wholeStr[i].charCodeAt(0)` can be simplified to `wholeStr.charCodeAt(i)`

Answer (score 0):

```
while(retVal[-1]===String.fromCharCode(0) ||
        retVal[-1]===String.fromCharCode(32))
    retVal = retVal.substr(0,retVal.length-1);
```

doesn't take care of it, because that doesn't test the last character. You can't use negative subscripts to index from the end (the `substr()` method implements this convention, but it's deprecated). To get the last character, use `retVal[retVal.length-1]`.